# autoreload webpage on new release

Tags: javascript, php

I have a website in PHP which is completely ajax-based.
There is an `index.php`, but a part from it, all the other pages are never rendered directly into the browser. Instead, all the post and get requests are done from JavaScript through ajax. So basically, if you go to `/contact.php` you will not see anything. All the pages are rendered inside `index.php`.

There are a lot of people that use this page that are not very web-savvy and may not understand what it means when we ask them to refresh the page.

The biggest issue happens when we do a new release. Especially the JavaScript code (but not only) can be the old one in a client's webpage as they maybe haven't refreshed the page for some weeks.

I perform an `svn update` to publish the new code to the server. Then I refresh my page and see the new features.

However, the people that don't really know how to refresh will not see anything. I have added a big button on the page with the text "refresh", which executes a `location.reload`.
This may help some people, but not everyone.

How can I "force" the browser to reload itself when a new version has been published?
I would prefer something simple which does not require additional libraries or a timer.

It is also quite important that the page not refresh when the user is doing something with the page, as they may lose work when this happens.

Comment: Why don't you force js reload with an extension?

Comment: What you mean? Can you explain?

Comment: function goto(who){
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET'
    ,url: 'pages.php'
    ,data: "page_name="+who
    ,success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR){
    //The server always returns version number which is no-cache and always up to date
    var server_version_nr = responseData.server_version_nr;
    var client_version_nr = $('#vers_nr').val();
    if(parseFloat(server_version_nr) > parseFloat(client_version_nr)){
    location.reload();
    }
    else{
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = responseData.content;
    }
    }
    });
    }

Comment: I came up to a solution by myself. Please feel free to discuss about it. the html contains an hidden field with the current version (current means when the user loaded the page last time). the javascript that makes the ajax-requests will get from php the lastest version's number. if that number is greater than the one in the hidden field, then js will perform an aoutreload.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can add a version constant in your code

```
 <?php

 define(VERSION, '1.0');
```

And everytime you call a javascript add this extension

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js?<?php echo VERSION ?>">
```

So when you'll update version, every js will be recalled by the navigator. Is it more clear?

You can also add a version check web service that will be called before any validate action, so you can refresh page or warn user before doing an action.

Without timer or socket.io you can't refresh page for user.

Comment: sounds good. i will try to implement it. seems like this could solve the problem. thanks a lot.

Comment: Wouldn't this still require a refresh to get the new version number? This would just prevent caching stale versions of `myfile.js`, I think.

Comment: Yes, this still requires one refresh. I was aware of it. would be great if this could be avoided. Is there another solution for this?